# web scraping to download pdf file from web using python but getting blank file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to download pdf report from web using python, however the code is returning a blank pdf report at the end, may i know whats wrong with the code and where i am going wrong.

=============================================

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imd.gov.in/Welcome%20To%20IMD/Welcome.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
b = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/")})
c = b[0]['href']
d = c[0:len(c)-12]

e = d + "PdfReportPage.aspx?ImgUrl=PRODUCTS/Rainfall_Statistics/Cumulative/District_RF_Distribution/DISTRICT_RAINFALL_DISTRIBUTION_COUNTRY_INDIA_cd.PDF"

def download_file(download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open("document.pdf", 'w')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

download_file(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the binary mode `b`

**Ex:**

```
def download_file(download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    with open("document.pdf", 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(response.read())
    print("Completed")

download_file(e)
```